# Private keys for a user with multiple devices

Tags: encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I know how basic RSA encryption works. When a user registers an account with my app on their device, a pair of private and public keys are generated. The public key is stored on the server, and the private is stored securely on the device.

When a user A wants to send text to another user B, the text is encrypted with user B's public key and then the user B decrypts it with his private key. It's all fine to this point.

However how will we handle a situation, where each user may be logged in to several devices? For instance, let's say my app is available in desktop and mobile. I can't share the private key between the two devices, since they are stored in the device only, and I don't think it is the best practice to share or transfer private keys around in the air.

So what is the best practice then? One solution that comes up to my mind is generating a new pair of keys unique for a device each time a user logs in from a new device. But then how would the user be able to decrypt messages sent from his other devices. I don't know what the best practice or solution is, I hope you guys can enlighten me on this issue.

Thanks in before :)

Comment: Sounds more like a topic for http://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: But: simply also sending the message to the public keys of all your other devices is an option…